# Can I make my full round multiple attacks with the same weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat

If I am level 6 with the attack progression +6/+1, can I use the same weapon to attack twice during a full-round action? If I am level 11 and get +11/+6/+1, can I use the same weapon to attack three times?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes, you can

The only time the game cares about which weapon you’re using is if you are using Two-Weapon Fighting (the bonus attack must be made with a different weapon from the main attack) and natural weapons (Claws, Bites, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, and if i have 2 weapons can i attack four times in full round action, two with one hand and two with another hand?

Comment: @Tom Only if you have at least BAB +6 and both the Two-Weapon Fighting and Improved Two-Weapon Fighting feats. Or BAB +16, when you can make 4 attacks in general: you can choose to make a main attack with any weapon you have, so you could choose to alternate, though it's usually better to use a two-hander and attack four times with that if that were the case.